# Tutorials on cram_designator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, are there better tutorials on how to use designators with cram_designator?

I have checked http://ros.org/wiki/cram_designators but the following part is really unclear for me

```
(def-fact-group navigation-action-designator (action-desig)
  (<- (action-desig ?designator ?goal)
    (desig-prop ?designator (type navigation))
    (desig-prop ?designator (goal ?goal))))
```

How do I interpret these codes?

- What are those things with question mark? Are they temporal variables?
- What is action-desig? In this case I think it is an action-designator type input instead of a function. So what does (action-desig ?designator ?goal) means?
- In cram_pr2 process module, I can find even more definitions like these but quite hard to understand the meaning. Do I need to learn some prolog?

Looking forward to reply!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48851/tutorials-on-cram_designator/) by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code above is Prolog code for the Lisp-based Prolog interpreter CRAM uses. Have a look at [cram_reasoning](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_reasoning) for more information.

All symbols prefixed with a questionmark are variables in the Lisp-Prolog-interpreter. That's actually pretty common syntax in most Lisp-based reasoning systems.

The code you pasted defines a predicate that holds for all designators that contain the properties `(type navigation)` and `(goal <some goal>)` and binds a variable to the actual goal.

action-desig? is a predicate that holds only for action designators. The predicate action-desig on the other hand is used by the method `reference` to resolve the designator.

If you want to use designators and maybe even implement your own, you will definitely have to learn some Prolog.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question marks are part of Lisp syntax, perhaps you could start by going over the basics of CRAM to understand what designators mean. A good starting point is http://ros.org/wiki/cram_language, and http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_pl/InternalTutorials

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Note that the internal tutorials might be pretty outdated and wrong at some points.

**Comment by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) on 2012-11-22**:
Could you give some pointers as to which (parts of the) tutorials are outdated?